# How to let 3 div columns extend the height until hit the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

This is my html:

```
<div class="head" style="height: 100px;"></div>  
<div class="wrapper">  
    <div class="col">col1</div>  
    <div class="col">col2</div>  
    <div class="col">col3</div>  
</div>
```

css:

```
.col{
    float: left;  
    width: 100px;
}
```

I'd like the three `div.col` have the same height, and the height is `page-height - 100`,
how to do that without JavaScript?(just css)
play with the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mdDwY/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using absolute positioning and use top and bottom on the columns.

Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/JYnrp/4/

The other thing you could do is use any of the equal height techniques like the one linked by Sinan and put a padding-bottom on the body of 100px to keep the columns 100px away from the bottom.

One more faux solution is if the 3 columns have simple background colors, then giving the wrapper a 1px high strip image with the 3 background colors in it and repeat-y that and then the columns will be different heights but will appear to be the same height.

Comment: what are those <br> s in your fiddle?

Comment: @Greg's right. They are not required for my solution to work.

Answer (score 2):

Matthew James Taylor's [Equal Height Columns with Cross-Browser CSS](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks) is an old standby.